# faild to connect to Mysql at 192..x.x.x:3336 through ssh tunnel at username@192.x.x.x:22 ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh, mobaxterm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyUWm.png)

"This is the result when I attempt to connect:

I'm trying to connect MySQL localhost to my session on the server. (I'm connected to my session on the server via SSH from MobaXterm)."

some one can help me pls <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: I'm sorry, but you should delete your question from SO as it is not about programming or software development, but about configuring database and network routing. The DBA sister-site of SO offers help in such matters.